# Gson - avoiding multiple classes for each action

Tags: java, gson

I'm working on a web game using JS, HTML5 websockets and Java as backend. I'm using Gson to serialize and deserialize json.

I made two classes, Message and Data to generate the JSON string below:

> { "message": setupGame, "data": {"width": 800, height: 800, "username": player1, "Ball": null }

Message class:

```
public class Message {

private String message;
private Data data;

public Message(String message, Data data) {
    this.message = message;
    this.data = data;
}
```

Data class:

```
public class Data {

private int width;
private int height;
private String username;
private Ball ball;

public Data(int width, int height, String username) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.username = username;
}

public Data(Ball ball) {
    this.ball = ball;
}
```

As you can see in the json string for setupGame the "Ball" is null as expected. I would like to achieve the json strings below:

Setup game:

> { "message": setupGame, "data": {"width": 800, height: 800, "username": player1 }

Game update:

> { "message": gameUpdate, "Ball": { "x": 600, "y":400 } }

I was thinking to make 2 classes for each action for example: SetupGameMessage,SetupGameData, GameUpdateMessage, GameUpdateData. But this would require me to create 10+ classes for all the json strings I need.

I wonder if there are better ways to do this in order to keep the code more maintainable and preventing all those seperate classes (Message and Data for every single action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your consumer is a language like JavaScript that isn't strictly typed, you can create a generic Request/Response object with just a tuple of "int code; String payload" and (de)serialize your service-layer POJOs into a JSON string and stuff it in the 'payload'.

That's a little hacky though, so I typically spend the effort to create specific, typed, Request/Response pairs for each specific endpoint.  This facilitates unit testing and avoids the problem of trying to create a POJO that does 'all things for all endpoints' which is probably a Really Bad Idea most of the time.

Check out google's [AutoValue project](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) - it takes almost all the pain of writing POJOs out of Java when you're staring down the barrel of making a bunch of classes.